# Posting raw data using node request library to also include newlines

Tags: node.js, node-request

I need to make a POST request using the node `request` library where the body will contain raw data as follows:

```
{ "delete" : { "_index" : "foo", "_type" : "bar", "_id" : "1" } }
{ "delete" : { "_index" : "foo", "_type" : "bar", "_id" : "2" } }
\n
```

Note that I have to include a newline after the end of the last object, I just added the `\n` to illustrate this.

I have used the request library to POST plenty of time before but for regular single JSON objects in the body.

In this case its multiple, and each needs to be on a separate line when sending to the endpoint I need to hit.

I am struggling to figure out what to use on the body param in the options supplied to the request call

Can someone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: Just pass the string you want to send as the body. If you need more help than that, you'll have to share your code.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some working code that covers converting an array of objects into newline-separated JSON with a trailing newline. It also shows how to send a raw string in a `POST` request using the `request` library. Hopefully one of those things covers the issue you were running into. If not, please clarify.

```
const request = require("request");

const url = "<REDACTED>";
const things = [
    {
        delete: {
            _index: "foo",
            _type: "bar",
            _id: "1",
        },
    },
    {
        delete: {
            _index: "foo",
            _type: "bar",
            _id: "2",
        },
    },
];

request.post(url, {
    body: things.map(JSON.stringify).join("\n") + "\n"
}, (err, response) => {
    if (err) return console.error(err);
    console.log(response.statusCode);
});
```